# Open cart page in new tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I need code to open a cart page in a new tab (nofollow) when I use the button located in the mini cart and the button that appears after a product is added.

WordPress and Woocommerce do not offer such an option. I couldn't find such code anywhere, and I don't have the knowledge to write one. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: I am using "Hello" theme.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's `window.open` function.

Here is an example using HTML and JavaScript:

```
<button 
onclick="window.open('https://www.yourwebsite.com/shoppingCart')"> 
Shopping Cart
</button>
```

Inline JavaScript is not recommended but, since this is just a very simple example, I think it's acceptable.

Comment: I need to use the (original) button that is located in the mini cart and the button 
that appears after a product is added.